# Secondary sorting by using join in Spark?

Tags: scala, sorting, apache-spark, rdd

In Spark, I want to sort an RDD by two different fields. For example, in the given example here, I want to sort the elements by `fieldA` first, and within that, sort by `fieldB` (Secondary sorting). Is the method employed in the given example good enough? I have tested my code and it works. But is this a reliable way of doing it?

```
// x is of type (key, fieldA) and y of type (key, fieldB) 
val a = x.sortBy(_._2)
// b will be of type (key, (fieldB, fieldA))
val b = y.join(x).sortBy(_._2._1))
```

So, I want an output that looks like the following, for example.

```
fieldA, fieldB
2, 10 
2, 11
2, 13
7, 5
7, 7
7, 8
9, 3
9, 10
9, 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But is this a reliable way of doing it?

It is not reliable. It depends on an assumption that during the shuffle data is processed in the order defined by the order of partitions. This may happen but there is no guarantee it will.

In other words shuffle based sorting is not stable. In general there exist methods which can be used to achieve desired result without performing full shuffle twice, but these are quite low level and for optimal performance require custom `Partitioner`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sortBy` in the following way

```
y.join(x).sortBy(r => (r._2._2, r._2._1))
```

Two sorting will happen in one go.

Comment: But for this I guess you will have to define the ordering variable on how to sort types of (A, B). No? There may be other methods, but my question relates to the approach I am using, if that one is reliable that is.